# Load many to many eloquent relationships data on vue component

Tags: laravel, vue.js, eloquent, edit

I am stuck in filling the form automatically during update in a Laravel Vue SPA.
I successfully have added the data during create. But I am lagging idea on how the related data can be filled during edit/update.

I have to load the data of Categories and Suppliers on Medicine create and update.

Model relationships:
**Medicine.php**

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'category_medicine', 'medicine_id', 'category_id');
}

public function suppliers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Supplier::class, 'medicine_supplier', 'medicine_id', 'supplier_id');
}
```

I have retreived the data from the api which looks like:

```
{
  id: 7,
  name: "Walker Stephens",
  generic_name: "Ian Farley",
  batch_number: "196",
  company: "Park and Steele Traders",
  strength: "Ullamco architecto c",
  description: "Et rerum et dolor cu",
  quantity: "150",
  purchase_price: "729",
  purchase_date: "1995-04-01",
  expiry_date: "2014-05-13",
  categories: [
  {
     id: 3,
     name: "Cancer",
     pivot: {
           medicine_id: 7,
           category_id: 3
            }
        }
     ]
   }
```

When I try to loop through `medicines.categories` inside the form, it gives an error as array expected got string even when the prop defined is set as array.

How can edit operation be achieved in vue component with many to many eloquent relationship?

P.S.: I am not using vuex here. And most importantly, the same form is being used in both create and update.

**Api call to the server**

```
 loadMedicines() {
  this.loading = true;
  axios
    .get("api/medicines")
    .then(({ data }) => {
      this.medicines = data;
      this.loading = false;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
},
```

The response looks as mentioned above in the code.

**Inside Medicine.Vue**

Now inside the medicine vue component, the category data has to be loaded but with selected option which was previously selected.

```
<select v-model="form.category"  name="category"  id="category" class="form- 
 control select2">
    <option value selected disabled>Select a category</option>
    <option v-for="category in medicines.categories" v-="category.id">
          {{ category.name }}
    </option>
 </select>
```

What might be the issue here?
Can we use eloquent relationships inside vue? If yes, how?

Comment: Share your vue code? Let us see what you are doing right now..

Comment: The question has been updated with all the sections sir.